# mediaelement.js player and phonegap couldn't work on .apk file

Tags: android, api, cordova, phonegap-plugins, mediaelement.js

I am trying to develop an application which is using mediaelement.js player. The styles, forward and backward buttons are not coming once I have created the android file. But it works in browser. Should I follow some other way to do this? When I searched, I have seen that to use media element API. But I cant find any API creation documents.

Comment: Have you already seen this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483187/is-mediaelement-js-compatible-with-phonegap?

Comment: thanks for the reply.. i have seen this. it works for me. but the problem is the styles i have used with mediaelement css not working when it is changed to .apk file. but perfectly works in browser.

Comment: And you should share some essential Informations: Android Version in use, are you using vendor-prefixing,"The styles, forward and backward buttons are not coming", is there nothing, does it look wrong, what says your Chrome Remote DEbugging